# Fourier transform of a convolution with upper limit not infinity

Tags: fourier-transform

The Fourier transform of a convolution

$$(f*g)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)f(x-y)\text{d}y$$

is just $G(t)F(t)$ where $G(t),F(t)$ are the transforms of $f$ and $g$. We also have that the transform of

$$\int_{-\infty}^tf(s)\text{d}s$$

is $\frac{1}{i\omega}\tilde{f}(\omega)+\pi\tilde{f}(0)\delta(\omega)$, which can be derived using the transform of the convolution.

But what would be the transform of

$$\int_{-\infty}^{t}g(s)f(t-s)\text{d}s,$$

can it somehow be derived using the above two transformations?

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tg(s)f(t-s)\,ds$. Then, $H(\omega)$ is

$$\begin{align}
H(\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^tg(s)f(t-s)\,ds\right)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(s)u(t-s)f(t-s)\,ds\right)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=G(\omega)\mathscr{F}\{uf\}\\\\
&=G(\omega)\,\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(F(\omega)*U(\omega)\right)\\\\
&=G(\omega)\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega-\omega')\left(\frac12 \delta(\omega')+\frac{i}{2\pi\omega'}\right)\,d\omega'\\\\
&=\frac12F(\omega)G(\omega)+\frac{i}{2\pi}G(\omega)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{F(\omega')}{\omega-\omega'}\,d\omega'
\end{align}$$

Comment: In the last line, is the $\omega$ supposed to be $\omega'$ in the argument of $F$ inside of the integral?

Comment: @dleal Indeed it is.  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Viola ! i learned with your answer.